# NullPointerException when getting a Real Path from ServletContext

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at this point on one page whereas on other pages its working fine.

```
String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().
                      getRealPath("/uploads/pictures");
```

I don't understand, why I am getting error?

Comment: is the other page also in session?

Comment: That code can never throw a `NPE`? Probably the problem is somewhere else. Can you show the surrounding code?

Comment: both action are having same code. In one action its working fine and in other giving null pointer exception.

Comment: @RohitJain: The error is on the same line.

Comment: try to get the method which throw `NPE` try first `servletRequest.getSession()` then `servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext()`, then `servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/uploads/pictures")` and you might find the cause.

Comment: At least provide proper code listing.

Answer (score 2):

Well I forgot to implement `ServletRequestAware` which was causing the error.
Solved now. Thanks all for your response.

Comment: You could also get request from `ServletActionContext` but this is more S2 like.

Answer (score 0):

The Servlets are more than  normal Java Classes. They need  WebContainer to execute and the output of some of the methods are purely dependent on the Web Container. Same happens with the "getServletContext().getRealPath()", if this method is executed within the WebContainer than it would return the path but if outside it (same as what you did) it will return Null values.
In order to use this outside the servlet, than from the servlet itself set the "path" in a session object or a request object.

Comment: [@Rohit Jain](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain) I think he have some web-resource mistake.